# SHGetFileInfo returns wrong icon for OneDrive folder

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to use `SHGetFileInfo` to get the icon for files and folders. I noticed that it does not work in one case: the OneDrive folder that is in my user profile folder. In that case, the call to SHGetFileInfo succeeds, but I get the default icon for an executable:

[image: What I get instead of the OneDrive icon]

Here is how I call the function:

```
HIMAGELIST imageList;
SHFILEINFO shfi;

// Get the path to the OneDrive folder
LPTSTR src = _T("%USERPROFILE%\\OneDrive");
TCHAR dest[MAX_PATH];
ExpandEnvironmentStrings(src, dest, MAX_PATH);

// Load the image from the OneDrive folder
ZeroMemory(&shfi, sizeof(shfi));
imageList = (HIMAGELIST)SHGetFileInfo(
    dest,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    &shfi,
    sizeof(shfi),
    SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);
```

And here is how I am drawing the icon:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    ImageList_Draw(imageList, shfi.iIcon, hdc, 0, 0, ILD_NORMAL);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
break;
```

I made a short self-contained example for the app on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/bdTvEQT5

In this short self-contained example I omitted any error checking code for brevity. Also, I have hard-coded the location of the folder for the purposes of the example. In my real app I am enumerating the folders in the file system and that's how I am getting the location of the OneDrive folder. The icon extraction code needs to work with any folder that is enumerated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are passing the (wrong) `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` flag, but are lucky enough to forget to set the `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` flag, so it gets ignored. The *OneDrive* folder is not a file. You need to go back to the documentation.

Comment: You don't check return values so don't know whether or not the API calls succeed

Comment: Please don't host your code on an external site. It belongs copy/pasted in the actual question.

Comment: @IInspectable I know that the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` gets ignored, but I did not know what to pass in there. I did not forget to use `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES`, I omitted it on purpose. If you know how I can get the icon for the OneDrive folder, please add an answer and I will be more than happy to accept it. I did read the documentation, please point me to the specific thing I missed if you know what that is.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The relevant parts of the code are embedded in this question. I considered the whole example to be too big to put in the question, because I did not want the question overlooked because it is too large to read.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I used the debugger to check the return values, so I know that the API calls succeeded. Otherwise, I would have gotten no icon. The code works for all folders, except the OneDrive folder.

Comment: Why would you choose to ignore error checking. Call me a cynic, but I see no reason to trust your hidden debugging.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The reason why I ignored the error checking was to keep the size of the example code to a minimum. Once I figure out why I'm not getting the right icon, of course I will add error checking. Do you think the lack of error checking is the reason why I'm getting the wrong icon?

Comment: I don't know what to think, because there are unknowns.

Comment: You really should display the values of imageList and shfi.iIcon in the titlebar so we can at least determine if the returned values make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me on Windows 10 (15031). You never use `shfi.hIcon` so you don't need `SHGFI_ICON` although it does not prevent it from working in my case but you are leaking a icon.

`%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive` might not be the location of the OneDrive folder. Never use environment variables when there are shell functions that can tell you the path!

You cannot assume that there is a OneDrive folder in the first place. If OneDrive has not been used then the folder does not exist on Windows 8.1 so you should handle failures from `SHGetFileInfo`!

I would recommend that you change your code to something like this:

```
PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;
HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderIDList(FOLDERID_SkyDrive, 0, NULL, &pidl); // Note: Change the flags if you want to create the folder if it does not exist
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    imageList = (HIMAGELIST) SHGetFileInfo((LPTSTR) pidl, 0, &shfi, sizeof(shfi), SHGFI_PIDL | SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);
    ILFree(pidl);
}
if (!imageList)
{
    // Fall back to a plain folder icon
    imageList = (HIMAGELIST) SHGetFileInfo(TEXT("DoesNotMatter"), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY, &shfi, sizeof(shfi), SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);
}
```

I cannot explain the result you are seeing and the lack of error checking certainly does not help. I'm guessing it is one of these:

- You are not calling `CoInitialize`/`OleInitialize` before calling `SHGetFileInfo`. MSDN does say you have to but it seems unlikely that it would return the correct image list but the wrong icon index.
- The OneDrive known folder registration is corrupted.
- The shell system image list is corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. Saying that my code worked for you was a huge help. The problem was in fact a corrupted OneDrive installation. The folder still showed up, but it did not work. I reinstalled OneDrive and now the icon shows up without modifying my code.
The reason I did not use known folders is that the code is meant to be used in a file browser-like app, so I need to get the icons from folders that are enumerated from the file system. I'm not using environment variables or making assumptions about where the folders are supposed to be.

Comment: @Ove: Your [mcve] does make assumptions about the location of a known folder, that could be set up somewhere else. That code should be rewritten to use the shell functions to look up its PIDL. You can ignore this advice in case your input is the result of enumerating the file system, as in your specific use case. This Q&A, however, knows nothing about your final application, and the question could be improved.